# how to convert doc into docx using power automate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, office365, power-automate

I have written a code in C# which converts doc file into docx file. the word documents are looking for template on network drive which is slowing the process. It is taking more than 20 mins to just open the doc file.

Is there any way using power automate/MS flow or any other MS technology which converts the doc into docx without getting connected to network drive for templates?

Comment: Yes, there's an action in LogicApps/PowerAutomate that will do it for you.  I'm pretty sure it's a paid service.  Lookup Cloudmersive.

Comment: Can you please provide me the associated link?

Comment: https://api.cloudmersive.com/microsoft-flow-connector.asp

Comment: It is for DOC to PDF convertor. Not able to find for doc to docx.

Comment: It’s there, you need to look harder. Just look in PowerAutomate or LogicApps directly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/cloudmersiveconvert/#convert-word-doc-(97-03)-document-to-docx